# SSH - kex protocol error: type 30 seq 1 [preauth]

Tags: ssh, openssh

After upgrade from ubuntu 18 to ubuntu 20 my SSH work well. But in some cases connections with some servers - user receive timeout. How to solve this?

Command `systemctl status ssh` shows:

```
error: kex protocol error: type 30 seq 1 [preauth]
```

SSH version:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is looking for some legacy options in ssh configuration.

Adding

```
KexAlgorithms +curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup4591761x25519-sha512@tinyssh.org
```

Solves error: `kex protocol error: type 30 seq 1 [preauth]`

You can set KexAlgorithms that way:

```
KexAlgorithms +<key_exchange_method1>,<key_exchange_method2>,...
```

The main point you can find:

```
man sshd_config
```